# BLoC does not yield state when requesting for a location in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There's three Flutter packages I am using to implement a functionality whereby a user pulls to refresh, a geo-coordinate is retrieved using BLoC logic and passed back to Flutter.

1. [Pull to Refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh)
2. [BLoC](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc)
3. [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

Trouble is, I cannot get the BLoC to yield the return result when I dispatch a call in **pull-to-refresh**.

**geolocation_bloc.dart**

```
class GeolocationBloc extends Bloc<GeolocationEvent, GeolocationState> {
  @override
  GeolocationState get initialState => GeolocationUninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<GeolocationState> mapEventToState(GeolocationEvent event) async* {
    if (event is RequestLocation) {
      yield* _mapGeolocationRequestLocation();
    }
  }

  Stream<GeolocationState> _mapGeolocationRequestLocation() async* {
    Position position;
    position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();
    print("RETRIEVED LOCATION"); // I CAN REACH HERE EVERYTIME.
    if (position == null) {
      yield LocationLoaded(0, 0);
    } else {
      yield LocationLoaded(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    }
}
```

Retrieves a geo-coordinate. If sensor is off/broken, return (0,0) instead.

**feed_page.dart**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _geolocationBloc.dispatch(RequestLocation());
  }

  void _onRefresh() {
    _geolocationBloc.dispatch(RequestLocation());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Username')),
      body: BlocProviderTree(
        blocProviders: [
          BlocProvider<PostBloc>(bloc: _postBloc),
          BlocProvider<GeolocationBloc>(bloc: _geolocationBloc),
        ],
        child: BlocListenerTree(
          blocListeners: [
            BlocListener<GeolocationEvent, GeolocationState>(
              bloc: _geolocationBloc,
              listener: (BuildContext context, GeolocationState state) {
                if (state is LocationLoaded) {
                  print('LOADED'); // THIS NEVER GETS PRINTED WHEN PULLED TO REFRESH.
                  lat = state.latitude;
                  long = state.longitude;                 
                }
..
```

The driver class dispatches a request `RequestLocation()` once in `initState()` and every time `onRefresh()` is called.

However, while the first time `RequestLocation()` is called it is passes successfully i.e. in `initState()`, subsequent calls using the **pull-to-refresh** `onRefresh()` method does not seem to yield the `LocationLoaded()` state.

**log**

```
Restarted application in 2,849ms.
I/flutter ( 6125): AppStarted
I/flutter ( 6125): RequestLocation
I/flutter ( 6125): RETRIEVED LOCATION
I/flutter ( 6125): Transition { currentState: GeolocationUninitialized, event: RequestLocation, nextState: LocationLoaded { latitude: 37.4219983, longitude: -122.084} }
I/flutter ( 6125): LOCATION LOADED
I/flutter ( 6125): RequestLocation
I/flutter ( 6125): RETRIEVED LOCATION
```

As per the log, the first call prints both **RETRIEVED LOCATION** and **LOCATION LOADED**, but nothing else occurs after the second **RETRIEVED LOCATION**.

How can I fix this such that the pull to refresh will successfully call on the BLoC logic which in turn return a `LocationLoaded()` object with the appropriate coordinates.

Comment: whats the value of position after the 2nd RETRIEVED LOCATION?  Is the gps location changing?

Comment: `I/flutter ( 6125): RequestLocation
I/flutter ( 6125): Lat: 37.4219983, Long: -122.084
I/flutter ( 6125): 37.4219983
I/flutter ( 6125): -122.084
I/flutter ( 6125): RETRIEVED LOCATION`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not looking to for the location to change in this case. The geo-coordinates are retrieved just fine, but the retrieved values are not passed on.

Comment: In the Bloc listener ```if (state is LocationLoaded) { ```  what values of state are you seeing?

Comment: There's nothing being printed out there i.e. LOCATION LOADED is not showing. I suspect the if statement is not being called at all.

Comment: Can you share the GitHub link for this? I am trying to implement something similar.

Comment: you can take a look at this: https://github.com/Carrein/whispery-1 but its very very old so caution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to solve this by removing the `Equatable` inheritance from my `State` and `Event` BLoC classes. `Equatable` implementation of equality checking resulted in the BlocListener not short-circuiting to the corresponding if/else block:

```
i.e. if (state is LocationLoaded)..
```

There is a possibility that the equality check is stricter in `Equatable` or since I'm passing two coordinates in the state (Latitude/Longitude), it causes the equality check to fail.

**State Class:**

```
@immutable
abstract class GeolocationState extends Equatable { // Remove inheritance.
}

class LocationLoaded extends GeolocationState {
}

class GeolocationUninitialized extends GeolocationState {
}
```

Comment: I once had some hierarchy of event classes and was checking them out of order and the same thing happened.

Comment: In my case, I need to @override List<Object> get props when childs have property.

Comment: the best practice is to keep 'Equatable' and override `props `