# state not yield in Flutter bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am building a test app in flutter bloc patter using flutter_bloc package. The problem is only the states of Event1 are rendered but the code executes in mapEventToState. I think the problem is with the yield statement because on triggering the Event2 the corresponding print statements in mapEventToState Executes.

The **mapEventTOState** function in page_bloc.dart

```
Stream<PageState> mapEventToState(PageEvent event) async* {
    print(event);
    if (event is Event1) {
      print(">> $event");
      yield State10();
      try {
        await someAsyncFunction();
        yield State11(message: "message");
        print("reached 100");
      } catch (e) {
        yield State12();
      }
    } else if (event is Event2) {
      yield State20();
      try {
        await someAyncFunction2();
        yield State21();
      } catch (e) {
        yield State22(message: e.toString());
      }
    }
    // TODO: implement mapEventToState
  }
```

The **page_state.dart** is as follows:

```
abstract class PageState extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class State10 extends PageState {}
class State11 extends PageState {}
class State12 extends PageState {}

class State20 extends PageState {}
class State21 extends PageState {}
class State22 extends PageState {}
```

The **page_event.dart** is given below

```
abstract class PageEvent extends Equatable {
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props => null;
}

class Event1 extends PageEvent {}
class Event2 extends PageEvent {}
```

The **BlocBuilder** is as follows:

```
child: BlocBuilder<PageBloc, PageState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      print(state);
                      if (state is State10) {
                        return Text("State10");
                      } else if (state is State11) {
                        return Text("State11");
                      } else if (state is State12) {
                        return Text("State12");
                      } else if (state is State20) {
                        return Text("State20");
                      } else if (state is State21) {
                        return Text("State21");
                      } else if (state is State22) {
                        return Text("State22");
                      }                       
                    },
                  )
```

The floating action button in Scaffold is as follows:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => pageBlocInstace2..add(Event2()),
        child: Icon(Icons.done),
      ),
```

And another widget in the scaffold is as follows:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => pageBlocInstace1..add(Event1()),
        child: Center(child: Text("Tap to here")));
```

Comment: I want to help you, but I can't understand what you mean in this sentence: "The problem is only the states of Event1 are rendered but the code executes in mapEventToState." and what's the problem.

Comment: @don-prog I have checked whether the code inside the if conditions work with print statements. The print statements in mapEventToStates are printed that means the event is triggered properly. I am not sure but I think the problem is with yield statement

Comment: @don-prog Is there any relation with my issue and this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641270/bloc-does-not-yield-state-when-requesting-for-a-location-in-flutter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was due to the fact that the two events call separate bloc instance.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => pageBlocInstace..add(Event2()),
        child: Icon(Icons.done),
      ),

GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => pageBlocInstace..add(Event1()),
        child: Center(child: Text("Tap to here")));
```

Comment: You saved my another day, after wasting one day, fortunately I found your answer. My luck its working. Thank you